# Is Nvidia's delta color compression supported in CUDA, or with DirectX UAVs?

Tags: gpu, compression, cuda

Nvidia discusses their lossless delta color compression is on its fourth generation in Pascal, and that it transparently saves bandwidth behind the scenes for rendering workloads. AMD has a similar technology, discussed in detail here: https://gpuopen.com/dcc-overview/

Do the same limitations apply to Nvidia's compression? They don't seem to discuss it in context of developer guidance.

Comment: As a designer of a GPU lossless image compression system, most of these seem to make sense, with the possible exception of using 32-bit float over 16-bit. Surely the LSBs of floating point data become increasingly less coherent and thus harder to compress.